# Using beginning regex characters in python

Tags: python, regex, string

I'm trying to implement regular expressions in python so that I will only print part of a string and not a whole string. I'm trying to print the characters that are numbers and also precede the letter characters of this string. I'm getting an error with the beginning of string character here

Heres my code
    import re

```
var = "20cw"
var2 = re.compile(^[0-9]?[0-9], var)
print var2
```

Here is the error I'm getting

```
  File "./temp.py", line 5
    var2 = re.compile(^[0-9]?[0-9], var)
                      ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Expected output is

```
20
```

Comment: Is there anything wrong with `if var[:2].isdigit(): print var[:2]`. Why leap at `re` for this?

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Sorry, I didn't give enough examples. The number in front is 2 digits in this example, but in my program it can 1 or 2 digits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose the regex as string (with quotation marks):

```
var2 = re.findall('^\d{2}', var)
```

Comment: Even better, use raw string (`r'^\d{2}'`) to avoid accidental interpretation of backslash character

Comment: @Błotosmętek sometimes useful, but irrelevant for this case

Comment: The regex you suggest is different from the original one. It must be `^[0-9]{1,2}` and if used with `re.match`, no `^` is necessary.

Comment: The regex is correct, from the description the OP wants to match on **exactly** two digits. It is OP's regex that is wrong.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew the regex OP used is not matching his requirements, `I'm trying to print the first two characters of this string IF the first two characters are numbers`